# How can I access a website which is protected via an. htaccess in JavaFX webview

Tags: .htaccess, webview, javafx

I'm using JavaFX webview to show different websites inside a JavaFX application. One is protected via htaccess, but the Webview doesn't show any popup to enter username and password.

Is this not supported at all by the webview or can I programmatically show a popup myself, collect the login credentials and hand them over to the webview somehow, so it get access?

Thanks

Comment: try this: 'http://username:password@domain.com'. it works frontend, not sure if in java console too. best regards